# Power BI shift from CET to EET timestamp

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Sorting data by date and hour in CET, shifting KWh measurements by one hour from CET to EET timestamp.

The problem involved sorting data in Power BI based on a column named "Date" containing CET dates and another column named "TQ" containing KWh measurements per quarter. The goal was to sort the data in ascending order starting from 01/06/2023, considering "is_ok" and "for_status" columns as TRUE, and shifting the timestamps from CET to EET timezone. Despite attempting various DAX calculations, the desired sorting and timezone conversion were not achieved, resulting in incorrect outputs.

The "Date" column in CET format contains dates like 01/06/2023. "Hour" lists 1-24 hours per day, while "Qrt" represents quarters (0, 15, 30, 45). Each hour may have multiple entries for quarters. "dispatchQrt" ranges from 1 to 96, starting from 1 for the first quarter of each hour. "TQ" holds KWh measurements per quarter for unique 5-digit codes. Sorting begins from 01/06/2023, with "is_ok" and "for_status" as TRUE. The goal is to shift TQ by one hour from CET to EET timestamp, transitioning from the last hour in June to the first in July.

Comment: The "Date" column in CET format contains dates like 01/06/2023. "Hour" lists 1-24 hours per day, while "Qrt" represents quarters (0, 15, 30, 45). Each hour may have multiple entries for quarters. "dispatchQrt" ranges from 1 to 96, starting from 1 for the first quarter of each hour. "TQ" holds KWh measurements per quarter for unique 5-digit codes. Sorting begins from 01/06/2023, with "is_ok" and "for_status" as TRUE. The goal is to shift TQ by one hour from CET to EET timestamp, transitioning from the last hour in June to the first in July.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated table to filter the main table:

```
FilteredData = 
FILTER(
    YourTableName,
    YourTableName[is_ok] = TRUE() && YourTableName[for_status] = TRUE()
)
```

Then with Power Query, you can sort the table the "Date".

Since CET is 1 hour behind EET, you can use a custom column in Power Query:

```
= DateTime.AddHours([Date], 1)
```